# How to change/remove blue panel glow in KDE4.6?

Tags: kde, appearance

After a system (as well as KDE) update, I got this blue panel glow which appears on hover.

[image]

I browsed through system settings, panel settings, desktop settings, but couldn't find an option to change/remove this blue glow. Did anyone else encounter this problem? Where should I look?

I also tried [this](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=90248), but it didn't help.

I use Arch, but don't think it matters much in this case...

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blue glow is not an effect, it's part of the Desktop theme. Don't use the **Oxygen** or a few other desktop themes. **Aya** should work for you

[image: System Settings - Desktop Theme - Aya Selected]

Here's what the resulting panel looks like, no blue glow

[image: kde panel using Aya]

Comment: hmmm, ok this works and points me into right direction. now I know where to look (where to change the color value). thank you!